# How to count cells in a table column that contains a specific text string (COUNT.IF doesn't work)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to count how many cells in a table column that contains a specific text string. I'm using this formula and it works well:

`=COUNT.IF(TB_table_name[col_name];"*string_to_be_found*")`

But I need to count only filtered cells.
I've found may solutions (using SUMPRODUCT) on internet, but only to common cells and not table conlumns.

This is the kind of table that I have:
[image]

As you can see, there are many values in the same cell (It happens because it is generated automatically by a survey made in MS Forms). Because of this, I need to search for a specific string to be counted.

Using "COUNT.IF" I have this results:

[image]

Please observe that the values in the cell are not random, but predefined - of course the sequence could not be the same, but the list of possible terms are.

Please, can you help me figure this out? Belive me, I have tried many things but nothing worked and it seems to be a thing so easy to achieve :(

Comment: Use the SUBTOTAL function on a *Totals* row.

Comment: Hi @Britto, what you have asked earlier **But I need to count only filtered cells.** and now made drastic twist to the question,,, and counting comma separated text string,,, please [edit] your post and be clear & loud what you are looking for !!

Comment: @Rajesh S Sorry if I didn't make my self clear, but I said since the begining what I'm trying to do with this generic formulae "=COUNT.IF(TB_table_name[col_name];"*string_to_be_found*")" and after you said that I did not show examples I imeediatly edit the question :|

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60950911/how-to-count-cells-in-a-table-column-that-contains-a-specific-text-string-count/60952295#60952295

Comment: Britto: you could write an answer based on the stackoverflow post. That would help future superuser readers to understand the solution.

Comment: @Britto,,, your question is an identical to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60950911/how-to-count-cells-in-a-table-column-that-contains-a-specific-text-string-count/60952295#60952295),, and it's combination of COUNTING specific Text String + After been filtered. There the OP has had shared the correct sample data but you this after many hours and it has created great confusion. And there also the key is SUMPRODUCT along with COUNTA supported with criteria.  Since you have already shared the link then I do feel needless to post it as answer !!

Comment: @Britto,, and let me say since you were the questioner there and got the solution then I'm unable to understand the why you have asked the same question here !! Don't you think that it's kills valuable time ? **And, please show me & others the method that how you filter any specific TEXT/ Word since many are comma separated, using AUTO FILTER ?**

Comment: Dear @ Rajesh S , I asked the question there, after I made it here, because I sincerely did not understand why so much confusion on your part Of course that, since the beginning, I really needed to offer more information! That was my fault ;)  Even in this way  @Máté Juhász got the point since the beginning. Besides this, thanks to be the first to give me an answer. ;) Peace!

Answer (score -1):

*Since OP has not provide any sample data therefore I've used a simple table to demonstrate that, how to `COUNT filtered data in Table's column`.*

**Situation 1:**

[image]

- Formula in cell `A35`:

`=SUBTOTAL(3,A23:A32)`

**N.B.** *`3` indicates `COUNTA` function in the  formula which `counts the number of non-blank cells`.*

*Drag formula right for other columns.*

---

**Situation 2:**

- Applied filter on `State` column for `MH` & `MP`.

[image]

[image]

- Now Filtered State are `MP` & `MH` and Product is `N`.

[image]

**N.B.** Since product `N` has been sold in state `MP` only that's why the `Count` is `2`.

[image]

---

**Note:**

- *Count and filtered data (result) depend on the filtered value in columns.*
- *The `SUMPRODUCT` formula can be used for all or for specific column/columns, depend on need*.

Comment: "I need to count how many cells in a table column that contains a specific text string"

Comment: @MátéJuhász,,  possibly U have ignored the Question's Title i.e. `COUNT.IF in a filtered table` is count the filtered data,, since filtering `SPECIFIC TEXT/DATA/VALUE`,, then ultimately is counting SPECIFIC text string !! **And if U check the TIME LINE the question has had been edited `17 Hrs` before (included new screen shots) and I've posted `21 Hrs` before ,,, I think this does makes some scene ,, why my post differs recent OUTPUT,, and I always expect from readers to consider all these before getting judgmental  !!**